# How to get Same result using instead of reduce()?

Tags: javascript

```
let arr = [2,4,3,6,90]

let res = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b
})

console.log(res);
```

I make this using by **reduce()**.
Now I want to make the same result by using another way in **pure javascript**.

```
function myReduce(arr, callBack) {

    let newReduce;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (newReduce === null) {

        }

    }

}
```

I tried to do by this code, but I could not make it work done.
so can you tell me some way? how can I get this result?

Comment: Is the first version not pure JavaScript?

Comment: Check out the polyfill and start from there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: `.reduce()` **is** "pure JavaScript".

Comment: give me some clue

Comment: i done this by using .reduce(). now i want to make reduce function mine which is bring same result

Comment: do you want "your" reduce to just sum the elements from an array? As another user said above, look at the polyfill from the docs, there is a function that works as reduce, you can base your code from there

Comment: i could not understand polyfill...

Comment: So you are not able yet to create your own `reduce` function... reduce is not a function that just sum elements from an array, it's much more

Comment: yes i want to make like this

Comment: i know it can make by callback function but don't know how to format this code and solve my code

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question here is, How to perform reduce operation without using the reduce operator.

The reduce operation's functionality is to take in multiple array values and reduce it or boil it down to a single value. 
Example:

```
[1,2,3].reduce((total,num)=>{
 return total + num
}, 0);
```

This would return 6. 0 here is the initial value that you want to start at.

In you case, the code would look something like this-

```
    let arr = [2,4,3,6,90];
    let total = 0;

    for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
    total += arr[i];
    }

    console.log(total);
```

Comment: I think you just did someone's homework assignment for them.

Comment: I wanted to post a comment but it wouldn't let me without enough rep. I thought I might as well try and explain the function. Probably should've avoided the last piece of code there.

Comment: no bro i just code for me not other than because i am just kid in coding haha

Comment: bro can you do that by callback function?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did this work to create my own reduce() with callback function.
I was tried to do that something different and thankfully, I get the result. here is my code. thanks for sharing your knowledge

```
let arr = [2,4,3,6,90]

function myReduce(arr, callBack) {

    let newReduce;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (newReduce === undefined) {
            newReduce = arr[i]
        }else {
            newReduce = callBack(newReduce, arr[i])
        }

    }

    return newReduce

}

let res = myReduce(arr, function (a, b) {
    return a + b
})

res
```

would you like it please vote my question...

Comment: I don't understand why you'd re-invent the wheel. `reduce()` has full support all the way back to IE9, and even if you were developing for an earlier browser, there's a perfectly fine polyfill. I understand to some extent that this might be a way to practice or learn, but this - *"would you like it please vote my question"* - seems like you're encouraging other people to support your custom `reduce` method, which if so, is silly.

Comment: bro just for practice nothing else